# Discriminated component props for react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to make discriminated component props, here's my code:

```
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react'

type SelectionModalProps<T> = (
  | {
      multiSelect: true
      onSubmit: (data: T[]) => void
    }
  | {
      multiSelect?: false
      onSelect: (nas: T) => void
    }
) & {
  data: T[]
  open: boolean
  title?: string
  onClose: () => void
  itemLabelGetter: (row: T) => ReactNode
}

const C = <T,>(props: SelectionModalProps<T>) => {
  return <></>
}

function Y() {
  return (
    <C
      data={[{ name: 'something' }]}
      itemLabelGetter={() => <></>}
      onClose={() => {}}
      open
      title="some title"
      onSubmit={() => {}} //  even though it works, this should give a type error
      onSelect={() => {}}
      //   multiSelect={true}
    />
  )
}
```

It almost works, but I am still able to pass the `onSubmit` prop, when I shouldn't be able to because the multiSelect is not true.

I want only when the prop `multiSelect` is equal to true to be able to pass `onSubmit`, otherwise, for example if it was explicitly equal to false *or if it was not provided* to not allow me pass the `onSubmit`, and instead the `onSelect` will become required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `never` to enforce the prop combinations in the union:

```
type SelectionModalProps<T> = (
  | {
      multiSelect?: never;
      onSelect?: never;
      onSubmit?: never;
    }
  | {
      multiSelect: true;
      onSubmit: (data: T[]) => void;
      onSelect?: never;
    }
  | {
      multiSelect: false;
      onSubmit?: never;
      onSelect: (nas: T) => void;
    }
) & {
  data: T[]
  open: boolean
  title?: string
  onClose: () => void
  itemLabelGetter: (row: T) => ReactNode
}
```

Comment: can you explain why you added  {
      multiSelect?: never;
      onSelect?: never;
      onSubmit?: never;
    }

Comment: @Normal that's to cover the case you mentioned above `if it was not provided`, without that you'd get the error `Property 'multiSelect' is missing`